# No JSON object could be decoded when the requested site is clearly JSON

Tags: python, json

I am writing a small python app which will update me about my portfolio on livecoin.net. I use the livecoin.net API as well as the coinmarketcap.com API. When requesting a page from the coinmarketcap.com API, which if you go to it (https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/) is clearly JSON, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/other/Desktop/livecoin.py", line 89, in <module>
    cmcData = getCoinMarketCapData(balances)
  File "C:/Users/other/Desktop/livecoin.py", line 22, in getCoinMarketCapData
    cmcData = json.load(cmcResponse)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

The page I'm getting is very clearly JSON as I said earlier, so I really have no clue why this is happening. Could anyone help me out?

I am well aware that this is not a site for charity code work, but I am very stumped and this was my plan Z... If you're willing to help there's no need to even write any code for me, just try to point me to where I'm wrong. Thanks :D

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import httplib
import urllib
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
from collections import OrderedDict

def getCoinMarketCapData(currencies):
    returns = {}

    cmcUrl = "api.coinmarketcap.com"
    cmcMethod = "/v1/ticker/"

    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(cmcUrl)

    for item in currencies:
        print item['name'].split(" ")[0].lower();
        print cmcMethod+(item['name'].split(" ")[0].lower())
        conn.request("GET", cmcMethod+(item['name'].split(" ")[0].lower()))
        cmcResponse = conn.getresponse()
        cmcData = json.load(cmcResponse)
        c = {"name":item['name'].split(" ")[0], "currency":item['symbol'],     "price_usd":cmcData[0]['price_usd'], "price_btc":cmcData[0]['price_btc'], "d1h":cmcData[0]['percent_change_1h'], "d24h":cmcData[0]['percent_change_24h'], "d7d":cmcData[0]['percent_change_7d'], "value":0.0}
    returns[item['symbol']] = c

    conn.close()

    return returns


def getData(dataDict, method, server, key, secret):
    encoded_data = urllib.urlencode(dataDict)

    sign = hmac.new(secret, msg=encoded_data,     digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()

    headers = {"Api-key":key, "Sign":sign}

    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(server)
    conn.request("GET", method + '?' + encoded_data, '', headers)

    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = json.load(response)
    conn.close()

    return data

def outputLine(key, value, prefix, suffix):
    spaces = ""
    pslen = len(prefix) + len(suffix)
    key = key.upper()
    key = " " + key + ": "
    keylen = len(key)
    x = 35-keylen-pslen
    for count in range(x-len(str(value))):
        spaces += " "
    return key + prefix + value + suffix + spaces

server = "api.livecoin.net"
balancesMethod = "/payment/balances"
coinInfoMethod = "/info/coinInfo"
api_key = "gEuyw7k4WvAhdXUmG36zHDksDZGR3fvq"
secret_key = "D4aTtN6tPxBqqDG24PFZ1238CMektp33"
responses = []
names = []
balances = []

namesJSON = getData([], coinInfoMethod, server, api_key, secret_key)['info']
for name in namesJSON:
    names.append({"name":name['name'], "symbol":name['symbol']})

data = OrderedDict([])
d = getData(data, balancesMethod, server, api_key, secret_key)
responses.append(d)

for currency in responses[0]:
    if currency['value'] > 0.0 and currency['type'] == 'total':
        for name in names:
            if name['symbol'] == currency['currency']:
                currency['name'] = name['name']
        balances.append(currency)

ownedCoins = []

for balance in balances:
    ownedCoins.append({"name":balance['name'], "symbol":balance['currency']})

print ownedCoins

cmcData = getCoinMarketCapData(balances)

for balance in balances:
    try:
        cmcData[balance['currency']]['value'] = balance['value']
    except:
    continue

for coin in ownedCoins:
    print coin
    item = cmcData[str(coin)]
    v = item['value']
    v = "%f" % (v)

    print "+-----------------------------------+"
    print "|" + outputLine('currency', item['currency'], "", "") + "|"
    print "|" + outputLine('amount owned', v, "", "") + "|"
    print "|" + outputLine('price in usd', item['price_usd'], "$", "") + "|"
    print "|" + outputLine('price in btc', item['price_btc'], u'\u20BF', "") + "|"
    print "|" + outputLine('% change 1h', item['d1h'], "", "%") + "|"
    print "|" + outputLine('% change 24h', item['d24h'], "", "%") + "|"
    print "|" + outputLine('% change 7d', item['d7d'], "", "%") + "|"
    print "+-----------------------------------+"
    print "\n"
```

Comment: What would you see printed if you do `print(cmcResponse.read())`?

Comment: @alecxe Thanks, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to load the json using the following code:

```
import urllib, json
url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

When i tried to use `json.load` instead of `json.loads` i got an error (different from yours) but it might give you a hint regarding what might be going wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!